# Геймпад от xbox series не видит система

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Такая проблема геймпад подключается по блютуз все соединяется но в системене отображается [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

установил xpadneo
а в /etc/bluetooth/main.conf вставил всё что надо
ос Linux mint 21.2

при чем все работало, но после перестановки ос перестало